# Can I create a Factory method which holds an internal reference to an instance of B?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design, factory

Given two classes:

```
class A {
    B* b_;
    A(B* b){
        b_ = b;
    }
}

class B {}
```

`B` is a class that should be used only inside `A` so I would like **not** to expose its creation to whatever class uses `A`. Moreover, `B` should **not** be created every time an instance of `A` is needed (it has a slow initialization).

Given that I would like to reuse the same instance of `B`, but I do not really need to make it **Singleton**, could be a good idea creating a **Factory** which holds an internal reference to an instance of `B`?

Something like:

```
class Factory {
    B* b_;
    A* createA() {
        if(b_ == NULL)
            b_ = new B();
        return new A(b_);
    }
}
```

My doubt is that I do not find anything useful googling for "stateful factory"  and maybe I overlook some drawback in this approach.

Comment: Do you intend the instance of `B` to last forever, e.g. until the program shuts down?

Comment: Probably yes. As I said `B` is slow in creation so it is better to reuse the same instance, but it is not mandatory to have only one instance: multiple instances don't break application logic, they only waste resources.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013650/threadsafe-lazy-initialization-static-vs-stdcall-once-vs-double-checked-locki

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-threaded environment, you may have multiple instances of B created simultaneously. Other than that, your design solves all of your requirements with  the least amount of code. In general, singletons complicate multi-threading in the future.

I would not call it a factory. It is a lazily initialized reusable instance.

Comment: So, I should mark as `static` the field `b_` of `Factory` (so I use the same instance of `B` at every creation of `A`) and protect its initialization with sinchronization logic, right?

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi that would protect the initialization but not the usage (i.e. any mutable data in the B instance). It depends on your needs.